# migrating legacy application with existing devise users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

A rails application is running an old version and needs to jump multiple generations. In addition, users were managed by devise in multiple tables, when the target is now to unify them.

The problem lies with databases and legacy encrypted passwords.  The [documentation provides indication as to legacy migration **TO** devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migration-legacy-database) , but not devise-to-devise.  While the db has the `encrypted_password` attribute, can this be carried over to a new database (seemlessly to the user) and how?

Comment: What is the old and new Ruby on Rails versions?

Comment: Rails 4.0 and Devise 3.5.2  to Rails 6.0 most recent devise

Comment: I suggest you to take backup of db and upgrade in local environment to find you are facing any issues. Most probably you won't face any issues as we have done similar migration and we didn't face any issue in our application.